# Fortran function calls raise Error: Statement function at (1) is recursive at compilation

Tags: recursion, compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran, fortran2003

I've inherited a legacy **Fortran 77** code that I now **try to** get to **compile in** the **Fortran 2003** standard. I have no clue about Fortran (I know C and Python), I'm picking it up on the way.

The below code snippet causes a compiler error (also given below). To be honest, just to look at this code gives me a head-ache: I really don't understand how one could write a line of code such as

A(i) = A(i) + B(q)

where both A and B are functions. I am familiar with the concept of recursive functions in C and Python, and if I were the compiler in this situation that is presented here, I would probably complain and raise at least a **WTF** warning.

I don't expect anyone to fix this code for me. I'd be more than happy if someone could explain to me what is (tried) to be achieved by the line:

```
cipr(IPR_WADV, ipa_idx, ispc) = cipr(IPR_WADV, ipa_idx, ispc) + fc1(l)/dy/depth(i,j,k)
```

or refer me to a good place where I can look that up.

Below are the code snippet and the corresponding compiler error.

```
IF( lipr ) THEN
    !-----Change from X-direction horizontal advection
    l = 1
    DO i=i1+1,i2-1
        l = l+1
       IF( ipa_cel(i,j,k) .GT. 0 ) THEN
          ipa_idx = ipa_cel(i,j,k)
          !-----Flux at west boundary
          cipr(IPR_WADV, ipa_idx, ispc) = cipr(IPR_WADV, ipa_idx, ispc) + fc1(l)/dy/depth(i,j,k)          
          !-----Flux at east boundary
          cipr(IPR_EADV, ipa_idx, ispc) = cipr(IPR_EADV, ipa_idx, ispc) + fc2(l)/dy/depth(i,j,k)
          !-----Average volume
          cipr(IPR_VOL, ipa_idx, ispc) = cipr(IPR_VOL, ipa_idx, ispc) + dx(j)*dy*depth(i,j,k)
          npastep(ipa_idx,ispc) = npastep(ipa_idx,ispc) + 1
          END IF
    END DO
END IF
```

the compiler gives this output message as an error

```
gfortran -std=f2003  -c -g -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/xyadvec.o
xyadvec.f03 xyadvec.f03:177.42:

cipr(IPR_WADV, ipa_idx, ispc) = cipr(IPR_WADV, ipa_idx, ispc) + fc1(l
                               1 
Error: Statement function at (1) is recursive
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `cipr` is an array, and somehow the compiler doesn't know that. In that case, the line is interpreted as being a statement function.

For example,

```
program dummy
dimension c(10)
c(i) = c(i) + d
end program
```

this will compile (besides warnings about unitialized variable usage), as `c` is an array and the line updates an element in the array, similar to what `c[i] += d` would do in C.

If c is not an array, then the line will be interpreted as a one-line function, similar to a macro. So, e.g.:

```
program dummy
c(i) = 2*i
...
myvar = c(2)
end program
```

here c is a function that returns twice the argument, so `myvar` would be 4.

So, in your case, I would guess from the usage that `cipr` is intended to be an array and there is something wrong with declaration of `cipr` or with some include files that declare the dimension of `cipr`. Because the compiler then interprets it as a statement function, it fails.

Can you give the entire file where this line occurs?

Comment: thanks for this answer. it's already very helpful. cipr is is definitely an array. I will put up the entire source file in a moment. The code snippet above appears around line 170. please bear with me, for the source is very unclean. I just got it on Friday and have only today started the cleaning.

Comment: I've put up the source file here: [http://sdrv.ms/16YwXhv](http://sdrv.ms/16YwXhv). I really appreciate your help, but you really don't have to go through all of this messy code (but I won't stop you if you wanna do it anyway ;-); your answer is exactly what I wanted and I've just made it the accepted answer. Cheers.

Comment: hmm, it asks to sign in, which I can't :). However, your remark about 'cleaning' the code, did you originally try to compile the old code without making any changes?

Comment: weird, I just tested it with another browser and I didn't have to sign in. try [this link](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=1D8FB5AA24222F6F!7533&authkey=!AIYpQMlmj993ATE)

yes, I compiled the code before; but with a very old version of PGI (pgi77, version 5.something). it ran without a problem.

however, we want to cast this code into the Fortran 2003 standard, we knew from the beginning that things like this would come up ;-)

Comment: thnx, I managed to download the file. I'm guessing it's the include files that are (you?) commented out that contain the dimension information for `cipr`?

Comment: yes, they do ;-) and yes, I have commented them out, because they also didn't compile in the Fortran 2003 standard. so that should solve the problem; i.e. I will fix those first. thank you so much!

Comment: a word of advice: if you go step by step and want to comment out include files, just start with adding the `implicit none` statement to all the program units. This will make the compiler stop if it doesn't know a variable.